# Django Exception Type: KeyError Exception Value: 'pk'

Tags: python, django, keyerror

I am probably doing something stupid but cant figure out what and it makes me insane since it is trivial and I have other apps working with same logic.

So I have  a Model Customer and Model  Notes. Each customer I can create a lot of Notes.
In Notes Customer is defined as Foreign key .

view.py

```
@login_required
def note_new(request,pk):
    contact = get_object_or_404(Contacts, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            note = form.save(commit=False)
            note.pub_date = timezone.now()
            note.save()
            return redirect('contact_details',pk=contact.id)
    else:
        form = NoteForm(pk=contact.id)
    return render(request, 'customer/note_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = [ 'title','body','contact' ]

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        contact_id = kwargs.pop('pk')
        # self.fields['contact'].initial = contact_id
        super(NoteForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.initial['contact'] = contact_id
        self.fields['contact'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

So form displays ok and after I click save I am getting

> KeyError at /customer/note/new/9
>   'pk'
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/note/new/9
>   Django Version: 1.8
>   Exception Type: KeyError
>   Exception Value:
>   'pk'
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\I812624\dev\mrp\src\customer\forms.py in `__init__`, line 48
>   Python Version: 2.7.1

It should redirect me to contact_details where contact info is displayed and it loops over all Notes.

contact_details.html

```
 {% for field in data.notes %}
    <tr>

       <td> {{ field }}</td>

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Shang has already explained why you are getting the error and how to fix it, so I won't repeat that. My answer is to suggest a different approach in your view.

If you don't want the `contact` field to be editable, it is best to exclude it from the form.

```
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Note
            fields = [ 'title','body']
```

Then in your view, you can set the contact after saving with `commit=False`

```
    if form.is_valid():
        note = form.save(commit=False)
        note.pub_date = timezone.now()
        note.contact = contact
        note.save()
        return redirect('contact_details', pk=contact.id)
```

Now you shouldn't have to override your form's `__init__` method at all.

If you want to display the `contact` in the template, then include it in the template context.

```
return render(request, 'customer/note_edit.html', {'form': form, 'contact': contact})
```

Then include `{{ contact }}` in the template.

Comment: Thank you @Alasdair you are correct , however I wanted to have a display  of contact   since it is on separate page form  so user will be always aware about the  contact the note is added for.

Comment: It would be better to pass the `contact` to the template context, and include `{{ contact }}` in the template. Note that the readonly widget is cosmetic. With the code in your question, the user could change the id that they submit, and create notes for any contact they wish.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you try to do this in your form `__init__`:

```
contact_id = kwargs.pop('pk')
```

but in your views.py method you didn't pass it to the form constructor. Change your `note_new` method to pass the `pk` in form:

```
form = NoteForm(request.POST, pk=pk)
```

A safer way for avoid the exception is to use default parameter for `pop`:

```
contact_id = kwargs.pop('pk', None)
super(NoteForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
if contact_id:
    # do something if pk is passed, otherwise contact_id is None
```